Как в Notepad++ заменить значение числа с математическим действием?
Имеется несколько сотен текстовых файлов с некоторым перечнем параметров.
В каждом файле имеется строка типа:

crs:Exposure2012="+2.67231">

В каждом из файлов значение crs:Exposure2012 уникальное.
Вопрос: как заменить значение в каждом файле, уменьшив его на 2?
Из примера выше: было +2.67231, стало 0.67231
В другом файле: было +0.51634, стало -1.48366
и так далее по всем остальным файлам.
Пробовал использовать плагин MultiReplace, но не разобрался с переменными.

В эксель загрузить

Спасибо всем откликнувшимся.
Использовал плагин MultiReplace в Notepad++:

Найти: \d*(\.\d{5})
Заменить: set(MATCH-2)
Опция - использовать переменные.
Заменить во всех открытых файлах.


Плюс и минус потерял - если было отрицательное число, то изменится не в ту сторону, а если число с плюсом стало отрицательным, то, вероятно, будут подряд плюс и минус.

Все верно. +- вторым этапом менял на -

Но вычитание из отрицательных всё равно неверное. Или отрицательных в файле не было?

Да, отрицательных значений не было. А какая бы была конструкция запроса с учетом знака "+" или "-"?

Не знаю, я не пользовался этим плагином.
